# Can one store a value indexed by a string in the IO monad?

Tags: haskell, io, purity

I want to use custom [ManagerSettings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.7.11/docs/src/Network.HTTP.Client.Types.html#ManagerSettings) to build a custom [Network.Wreq.Session](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.3.3/docs/Network-Wreq-Session.html). I modify from the [defaultManagerSettings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.7.11/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:defaultManagerSettings) both `managerRawConnection` and `managerModifyRequest`.

I want `managerModifyRequest` to use a configuration value known at runtime from a file. As I do a lot of requests, I would rather not make a lot of syscalls to get the configuration value from the file.

I find the type `managerModifyRequest :: Request -> IO Request` to be problematic. How can I use a configuration value if it is not possible to get it from the parameters?

I thought about [IORefs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) and [MVars](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) to store the value in memory, but I should be able to pass said IORef or MVar to the function somehow...

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "is not possible to get it from the parameters". In what sense it is not possible? Also, why reading a value from e.g. an `IORef` is more problematic than reading one from a file?

Comment: For the first question, because there is only a `Request` parameter to the `managerModifyRequest` function. For the second one, because I can use the filename to get the configuration value.

Comment: Your function that reads from a file returns `IO Something`. Your function that reads from an IORef or `MVar` also returns `IO Something`. It isn't clear why one is more problematic than the other. Can you show some code that works, even inefficiently, with values stored in a file? What exactly stops you from modifying this code to use an IORef instead?

Comment: Reading each time from a file is costly. @chi showed a working example. I did not realize I could use `>>=` to use a pure function with a custom IO value.

Comment: I was wondering what doesn't let you come up with this exact kind of example. There isn't anything particularly custom about any IO value. You use >>= (or do notation) when reading from a file or reading from an IORef in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library, but I guess you need to write something like this:

```
-- pseudocode
foo = do
   -- create the IORef here
   r <- newIORef "hello"
   let settings = defaultManagerSettings{
          ...
          managerModifyRequest = \req -> do
             -- use the IORef here
             s <- readIORef r
             putStrLn s
             writeIORef r (s ++ "!!")
             return req
          }
   use settings
```

You don't need to pass the `IORef` as an additional argument to `managerModifyRequest` , you need to define that `Request -> IO Request` function in the scope where the `IORef` is available.

---

Alternatively, use an helper function with the additional argument, and then partially apply it with the `IORef`:

```
-- pseudocode
foo = do
   -- create the IORef here
   r <- newIORef "hello"
   let settings = defaultManagerSettings{
          ...
          managerModifyRequest = myManager r
          }
   use settings

myManager :: IORef String -> Request -> IO Request
myManager r req = do
   -- use the IORef here
   s <- readIORef r
   putStrLn s
   writeIORef r (s ++ "!!")
   return req
```